# Android: progress wheel error

Tags: android, eclipse, show, progressdialog, android-progressbar

Goodevening, im trying to create a progress spinning wheel when an onClick function start but i got an error from eclipse and seems it won't work.

here is my code

```
    hwdebug.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ProgressDialog MyDialog = ProgressDialog.show( this, "TEST" , "Loading. Please wait ... ", false);
                  // FUNCTION
            MyDialog.dismiss();
                                    }
    }
```

The error im getting from eclipse is that:

> The method show(Context, CharSequence, CharSequence, boolean) in the
>   type ProgressDialog is not applicable for the arguments (new
>   View.OnClickListener(){}, String, String, boolean)

Any suggestion? Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
ProgressDialog MyDialog = 
       ProgressDialog.show( this, "TEST" , "Loading. Please wait ... ", false);
```

to

```
ProgressDialog MyDialog =
                          ProgressDialog.show( CurrentActivity.this, "TEST" ,
                                 "Loading. Please wait ... ", false);
```

use Current Activity Context instead of View to show ProgressDialog or you can get Context by using `v.getContext()`

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
ProgressDialog MyDialog = ProgressDialog.show( yourActivity.this, "TEST" , "Loading. Please wait ... ", false);
```